# Is there a limit on the number of work orders I can have active?

Tags: mary-skelter-nightmares

Early on, you get access to the Liberated District, which acts as the central hub, with a general store, armory, and the Order HQ, which essentially gives side quests that you can accept.

[image: order HQ]

Since it's a dungeon crawling RPG, it reminded me of the Request system in Persona 3. However, after accepting a few, I wondered if I could just accept all of them and have them *all* active at the same time. It allowed me to do this, but as I'm only at the very beginning of the game, I figured there might be a point later on where there may be too many available work orders to have active at the same time. Is this the case and if so, what is the limit?

Comment: I don't think there is one. I also took all of the first batch of work orders and continued to do so for every batch. Though, I am also constantly clearing some one so I can't say for sure if there would be a limit.